# What's the name of Perl distribution units?

Tags: perl

Package is a namespace. Module is a file with Perl code. `cpan` and `cpanm` are probably package managers. When I do [`cpanm XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/release/XML-LibXML) I install what exactly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Distribution (or "dist" for short).

The name for a Perl distribution unit is *distribution*, so `cpanm XML::LibXML` installs the XML-LibXML *distribution*, because it includes the specified XML::LibXML *module*.

***Example 1***

[image: Screenshot of meta::cpan using the word "distribution"]

***Example 2***

[image: Screenshot of meta::cpan using the word "distribution"]

Note that linux distributions usually have a package manager such as `apt` or `yum`, and many Perl distributions are made available as *packages* for those package managers. Someone using those package managers might refer to Perl distributions as packages, but that's not standard Perl jargon.

Answer (score 3):

When you download a package with a name like "UseFull::Munger"

You will at the very least get a file UseFull/Munger.pm installed in your perl library.

You could also get a set of modules used to implement the main module: "/UseFull/Munger/dyslexic.pm".

The module may be a wrapper around a C library (like LibXML) in which case you will get some binaries installed such as  "auto/XML/LibXML/LibXML.so".

If cpan needs to build a wrapper for a library you will get some "UseFull/Munger/SlickClib/SlikClib.xs" files which tell CPAN how to build the perl wrapper.

In addition, if the developer is nice, you may get lots of ".pod" document ion on how to use the module.

Comment: In other words, the word "package" has too meanings: namespace, where functions and variables are declared, and unit of distribution?

Answer (score 2):

I call these *Perl modules* or *CPAN modules*. The individual .pm building blocks are *Perl modules* too, but you rarely use them directly.

When talking about the archive file that you upload to CPAN, you can use the word *distribution*. When talking about all the other files that are in there and that you can view on metacpan, taking a look *at the dist(ribution)* works well, too.